# How to add authentication account controller after creating a project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, controller, visual-studio-2017

I'm working on a project in VS 2017. I've forgotten to add authentication during creating project. Now, i want to add account controller without losing or creating a new project. How can it be possible?

Thnaks

Comment: One way would be to create a new project and copy the relevant bits into your current project. But without knowing what type of authentication you want or how you want it configured, there isn't much help anyone can provide here.

Answer (score 0):

In .net Core 2.1, Identity can be scaffolded in:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authentication/scaffold-identity?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=visual-studio

This system is quite useful, because it allows you configure many little known Identity features in the scaffold dialog like 2FA and password resets. All that is left is to style the views, saving a bunch of time, since the functionality is pretty universal. The identity system even allows for a 2FA app if you really want to be secure! SMS isn't ideal for crypto apps because it can be hijacked!

The default configuration of 2.1 when you select identity/auth for your project is quite spartan and probably won't be much use except for a tutorial. The views I believe are implemented as a Razor Pages library, so the Views folder will not have any Login/Register pages.

Also, The injection in Startup.cs `ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)` only allows for an `IdentityUser`.  You probably want to extend this model with more fields like First and Last Name, Date Registered, Last Login etc.

```
services.AddDefaultIdentity<IdentityUser>()
                .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```

vs.

```
  services.AddIdentity<EnhancedUserAcct, IdentityRole>()
              .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>();
```